# Keen io limit clause for .net

Tags: keen-io, keen-js

Does anyone know a workaround for the limit clause in .NET? I keep getting error 429: Your extraction is too large to process synchronously and need to limit the resultset without changing the query filters.

Comment: The Keen documentation mentioned this is not yet implemented for .NET so I am looking for a workaround if anyone has one [link] (https://keen.io/docs/api/?c#order-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `limit` does not currently work with extractions, only with `group_by`. You can use the `latest` parameter (see the [extraction docs](https://keen.io/docs/api/#extractions)) to achieve something similar; I'd have to research the exact syntax for adding that to a query in the .NET SDK, but it looks like it should be possible with one of the more flexible method overrides.

That said, a better solution to this problem is using a smaller timeframe. That will reduce the number of events being scanned by the extraction. You can then run a series of such extractions to get the full data you needed. For example if you're currently trying to extract the past week of data in one call, you can try extracting each day one at a time.

FYI: I am the Chief Platform Architect at Keen.

Comment: Thank you, "latest" worked for my specific scenario. Limit would be great if implemented for .NET but latest is a good workaround so I can show results instead of the error message.